# Generate DataFrame from Nested Dictionary

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a nested dictionary like below:

```
[
    {
        "name": "A",
        "flag": "folder",
        "children": [
            {
                "name": "A1",
                "flag": "folder",
                "children": [
                    {
                        "name": "A1x",
                        "flag": "file",
                        "children": []
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "A1y",
                        "flag": "file",
                        "children": []
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

From this dict, I would like to generate a dataframe as below:
[image]

Is there any nice way to make this?

Answer (score 0):

With the following nested dictionary which expands on yours for demonstration purposes:

```py
data = [
    {
        "name": "A",
        "flag": "folder",
        "children": [
            {
                "name": "A1",
                "flag": "folder",
                "children": [
                    {
                        "name": "A1x",
                        "flag": "file",
                        "children": [{"name": "A1xx", "flag": "file", "children": []}],
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "A1y",
                        "flag": "file",
                        "children": [{"name": "A1yy", "flag": "file", "children": []}],
                    },
                ],
            },
            {
                "name": "A2",
                "flag": "folder",
                "children": [
                    {
                        "name": "A2x",
                        "flag": "file",
                        "children": [{"name": "A2xx", "flag": "file", "children": []}],
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "A2y",
                        "flag": "file",
                        "children": [{"name": "A2yy", "flag": "file", "children": []}],
                    },
                ],
            },
        ],
    },
    {
        "name": "B",
        "flag": "folder",
        "children": [
            {
                "name": "B1",
                "flag": "folder",
                "children": [
                    {
                        "name": "B1x",
                        "flag": "file",
                        "children": [{"name": "B1xx", "flag": "file", "children": []}],
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "B1y",
                        "flag": "file",
                        "children": [{"name": "B1yy", "flag": "file", "children": []}],
                    },
                ],
            },
            {
                "name": "B2",
                "flag": "folder",
                "children": [
                    {
                        "name": "B2x",
                        "flag": "file",
                        "children": [{"name": "B2xx", "flag": "file", "children": []}],
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "B2y",
                        "flag": "file",
                        "children": [{"name": "B2yy", "flag": "file", "children": []}],
                    },
                ],
            },
        ],
    },
]
```

Here is one way to do it by defining two short helper functions:

```py
import pandas as pd

def traverse(data, new_data=None):
    """Recursive function to go through dict of values.

    Args:
        data: target dict.
        new_data: container. Defaults to None.

    Returns:
        Flatten data.

    """
    new_data = new_data if new_data else [[]]
    new_data[-1].append(data["name"])
    new_data[-1].append(data["flag"])
    for child in data["children"]:
        traverse(child, new_data)
    new_data.append([])
    return new_data


def make_rows(flat_data):
    """Custom function to shape data.

    Args:
        flat_data: target data.

    Returns:
        Dataframe.

    """
    rows = [[]]
    for item in flat_data:
        if item:
            rows[-1] += item
        else:
            rows.append([None for _ in range(int(len(rows[-1]) / 2))])
    return pd.DataFrame(rows).dropna(how="all").fillna(method="ffill")
```

And then:

```py
df = pd.concat([make_rows(traverse(item)) for item in data]).reset_index(drop=True)
df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_product(
    [[f"Level {i}" for i in range(int(df.shape[1] / 2))], ["name", "flag"]]
)
```

```py
print(df)
# Output
  Level 0         Level 1         Level 2       Level 3      
     name    flag    name    flag    name  flag    name  flag
0       A  folder      A1  folder     A1x  file    A1xx  file
1       A  folder      A1  folder     A1y  file    A1yy  file
2       A  folder      A2  folder     A2x  file    A2xx  file
3       A  folder      A2  folder     A2y  file    A2yy  file
4       B  folder      B1  folder     B1x  file    B1xx  file
5       B  folder      B1  folder     B1y  file    B1yy  file
6       B  folder      B2  folder     B2x  file    B2xx  file
7       B  folder      B2  folder     B2y  file    B2yy  file
```